# int x; scanf() with %d and printf() with %c

Tags: c, format-specifiers, conversion-specifier

int x;
So there will be 2 bytes memory for the variable.
Now, if I entered 66 and because scanf() with %d, 66 will be stored in 2 bytes memory because the variable is declared int.

Now in printf() with %c, should collect data from only one byte memory to display.

But %c displayed correctly B by getting correct data 66 from memory to display.

Why it %c has not just get data from one byte?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note that an `int` must be _at least_ 16 bits wide, but may be, and commonly is, wider....

Comment: Wildly guessing, your int is converted implicitly to char, keeping the value 66, which fits into the 8bit of a char. Without MCVE, being more precise is impossible.

Comment: @Yunnosch - No MCVE is necessary - this behaviour is well-defined.

Comment: "it %c has not just get data from one byte?" --> it gets the 2 (or 4) bytes and then ignores all but 1 for printing.

Comment: Um... How did you decide that `%c` got its data "from two bytes"? `66` is a number that fits perfectly fine into just one byte. Maybe your `%c` used that one byte. Where is the evidence of two bytes being used by `%c`??? Without it the question makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: How %c can get data from two or more bytes? Is it not limited to get data from one byte?

Answer (score 6):

`%c` *expects* an `int` argument, due to the *default argument promotions* for vararg functions.  In other words, all of the following are exactly equivalent:

```
int x = 66;
char y = 66;
printf("%c", x);         // A
printf("%c", (char)x);   // B
printf("%c", y);         // C
printf("%c", (int)y);    // D
```

So all that's happening is `printf` is interpreting the `int` value of 66 as an ASCII code<sup>1</sup> and printing the corresponding character.

---

<sub>1. Note that ASCII is technically an implementation-defined design decision.  Just an overwhelmingly common one.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The `%c` conversion specifier in a `printf()` statement expects an `int` argument. Further, since `printf()` is a variadic function, a `char` is converted to an `int` by virtue of [the default argument promotions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6).

The `int` argument that is passed to `printf()` corresponding to a `%c` specifier is then [converted to an `unsigned char`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8) by `printf()` before printing. [Note that the conversion of a `signed` integer type to an `unsigned` integer type is well-defined in C](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3), and does not involve collecting "data from only one byte." Rather, if the new type can hold the original value, the value remains unchanged; otherwise one larger than the maximum value for the new type is added to (or subtracted from) the old (`signed`) value. For example, an `int` value of `-1` would be converted to an `unsigned char` value (assuming `UCHAR_MAX` is 255) of `-1 + 256`, or `255`, which is within the range of an `unsigned char`.

Note that an `int` with a value of `66` would be unchanged in the conversion to `unsigned char`, since 66 is well within the range of an `unsigned char`. `UCHAR_MAX` must be a *minimum* of 255.

Comment: Where does the OP mention he is passing a `char` to `printf`?

Comment: @chqrlie-- Nowhere, as far as I can see; just adding a detail about why `printf()` expects an `int`, yet it is typical to pass a `char` with the `%c` conversion specifier.

Comment: Good point.  To add to the confusion, `'a'` is actually an `int` in C (unlike ++).

Comment: @chqrlie-- that is also a good point, that character constants are type `int` to begin with. Is it any wonder that this stuff is a little confusing for learners?

Comment: 'A' is actually a int in C I know that. That I think equal to 65 and saved in memory as corresponding binary value combination of 8 0s and 1s as binary code.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how the argument is passed, the `%c` format specifier always converts its argument to `unsigned char` before printing it. So, `%c` always prints one byte.

Your assertion that `%c` gets its data from more than one byte is unfounded. The example presented does not show any evidence to the contrary - `66` is a number that fits into one byte.

The intricacies of variadic argument passing (yes, it is passed as an `int`) have no bearing on the observed behavior in this case.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems that OP believes that `%c` expects a `char`, and is confused about what may happen when the actual argument is wider than a `char`; hence my attempt to describe the goings-on. Maybe also confused about representation of integer types....

Comment: Yes Sir. I am confused about what may happen when the actual argument is wider than a char size i.e. one byte. Then data more than one byte should go to where in memory? Because there is only one byte that relates to char variable.

Comment: I know that char is actually nothing just an integer

Comment: But memory size of char binary code is just one byte